# Create workers dynamically (ActiveMQ)

Tags: web-services, activemq-classic

I want to create a web application were a client calls a REST Webservice. This returns OK-Status for the client (with a link to the result) and creates a new message on an activeMQ Queue. On the listeners side of the activeMQ there should be worker who process the messages.

Iam stucking here with my concept, because i dont really know how to determine the number of workers i need. The workers only have to call web service interfaces, so no high computation power is needed for the worker itself. The most time the worker has to wait for returning results from the called webservice. But one worker can not handle all requests, so if a limit of requests in the queue is exceeded (i dont know the limit yet), another worker should treat the queue.
What is the best practise for doing this job? Should i create one worker per Request and destroying them if the work is done? How to dynamically create workers based on the queue size? Is it better to run these workers all the time or creating them when the queue requiere that?

I think a Topic/Suscriber architecture is not reasonable, because only one worker should care about one request. Lets imagine of 100 Requests per Minute average and 500 requests on high workload.

My intention is to get results fast, so no client have to wait for it answer just because not properly used ressources ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you figure out the max number of workers you'd realistically be able to support, and then make that number and leave them running forever?  I'd use a prefetch of either 0 or 1, to avoid piling up a bunch of messages in one worker's prefetch buffer while the others sit idle.  (Prefetch=0 will pull the next message when the current one is finished, whereas prefetch=1 will have a single message sitting "on deck" available to be processed without needing to get it from the network but it means that a consumer might be available to consume a message but can't because it's sitting in another consumer's prefetch buffer waiting for that consumer to be read for it).  I'd use prefetch=0 as long as the time to download your messages from the broker isn't unreasonable, since it will spread the workload as evenly as possible.

Then whenever there are messages to be processed, either a worker available to process the next message (so no delay) or all the workers are processing messages (so of course you're going to have to wait because you're at capacity, but as soon as there's a worker available it will take the next message from the queue).

Also, you're right that you want queues (where a message will be consumed by only a single worker) not topics (where a message will be consumed by each worker).

Comment: Thank you for your tip. Maybe its really a question of "trial and error" to figure out, how many load one client can take. I think i'll also implemenent a monitor which shows and automanage the the current workers and the load balancing of them at all.

Comment: Load balancing should happen automatically if you do what I suggest and set prefetch=0.  But yes, you need to figure out how many messages you can process in parallel and no one but you will be able to figure that out, since it depends on your hardware, on what work is done for each message and on what other environmental load your system might be under.  And although trial and error is one way to do it, you can probably zero in on a good starting point for your trial and error by measuring the performance load of one worker and determining what fraction of the total resources that represents.

Comment: Yes, i dont really ment the "load balancing" this is given in this case, but i just want to have a possibility to set configuration at runtime, for exmaple setting a start number of workers and just if i see that there are still messages to process, but no worker is free i have to speed up my hardware (so i can add more worker) or just add another machine which treads the pool.

Comment: It is really difficult to figure out whats the maximum load for 1 physical device, i think its only limited by the connection, because it hasnt to do any work